# The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, minio

I am using a third party library ([MinIo dotnet SDK](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/dotnet/minio-dotnet.html)) in my .NET application. I successfully send the requests on the localhost, but at the time of publish on the IIS server, the requests are met with the following error.

```
MinIO API responded with message=Connection error:The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.. Status code=0, response=The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception., content=
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here this week.

We had to install the (root) certificate we used for our minio/S3 server on the machine we ran our application on.

If you don't want to use SSL, you have to use MinioClient.WithSsl(false).